# Symfony OneToMany Assiociations not working

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have Product entity and ProductAttachment entity. One product should be able to have many attachments. I Used Doctrine mapping OneToMnay - ManyToOne but everytime i get product, it has empty $files collection

ProductAttachment Entity

```
     * @var \Shopsys\ShopBundle\Model\Product\Product
     * 
 @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shopsys\ShopBundle\Model\Product\Product", inversedBy="files")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $product;
```

Product Entity

```
     * @var \Shopsys\ShopBundle\Model\Product\ProductAttachment[]|\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Shopsys\ShopBundle\Model\Product\ProductAttachment", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    public $files;

    public function getFiles()
    {
        return $this->files;
    }
```

Am i Missing anything?

When i call

```
dump($product->getFiles());
```

this is what i get

```
Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection #619d
   snapshot private => array ()
   owner private => Shopsys\ShopBundle\Model\Product\Product #e2e7
   association private => array (15)
   em private => Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager #dfae
   backRefFieldName private => "product" (7)
   typeClass private => Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata #5e75
   isDirty private => false
   collection protected => Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection #57e3
   |  elements private => array ()
   initialized protected => false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Doctrine's lazy loading of collections, which is indicated on the `PersistentCollection` object's `initialized` property - which is `false` in your case. Meaning, it wasn't initialized.

This is usually pretty smart, since you usually don't need all of your entities relations loaded (and those related entities could have relations themselves etc.). Instead, the persistent collection will act as a proxy / wrapper and only load the collection contents once some part of the collection is actually accessed.

Some collection implementations have some interesting behavior, so I would advise to not expose collections to the "outside" of your entity. So my advice is to change the `getFiles` to `return $this->files->toArray()` and making the `$files` property `private`.

However, that's just an advise. In any case, you calling `toArray()` on any collection should initialize it and make it behave like the array you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution of Jakumi. It just didn't work for me. What worked for me in the end was (Symfony 4.4)

```
public function getItems()
{
    return iterator_to_array($this->items);
}
```

Calling the function immediately fills the collection in the object as well.